# Perl print %hash - need some help to understand this

Tags: perl

Every simple Perl code but I don't understand it.

Here we go

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
my %hash;
$hash{"key"} = "value";
$hash{"key2"} = "value2";
$hash{"key3"} = "value3";
print %hash."\n";
```

And result is `3/8`, remove one kep=>value pair, result is `2/8`

If I removed the `."\n"` then the result is expected `key3value3key2value2keyvalue1`

No reason to do this, noticed this accidentlly just try to understand what is happening.

Comment: In case you aren't already aware, Data::Dumper is useful when you need to dump data structures i.e. `use Data::Dumper; print Dumper \%hash;`.

Comment: I wish I could upvote comments. Dumper, ftw.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you append the "\n" to the hash, you force the hash to be interpolated in scalar context, which causes it to print out its current capacity and size.  When you remove it, the hash is interpolated in list context, and it prints out its current key/value pairs.

Comment: note that it is not the "\n" in particular; it is giving the hash as an operand of the `.` operator that gives it scalar context.

Comment: As ysth pointed out it is concatenation that is causing the issue (thanks for pointing that out). It is probably better to supply multiple arguments to the print function as oppose to a single concatenated string i.e. `print %hash, "\n";` which will produce the expected result.

Answer (score 3):

While Mark has covered what's going on here perfectly already, you can get the intended result without forcing the hash into scalar context by using "say %hash;" in versions of perl from 5.10 onwards or so.

You'll need to `use feature 'say';` just as you would `use warnings;` (or to be running under perl -E, which switches on a number of "newer" features)